# Passing Scatter Plot Marker as Function Parameter in Julia Using PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, marker

I'm trying to pass the marker setting to a scatter plot in Julia using PyPlot as the backend - Julia uses the "`marker=:star`" syntax, for example; how do I pass this "`:star`" setting as a function parameter (this doesn't work as a string)?

Function Call (Doesn't Work):

```
   using DataFrames
   pyplot()

   df=DataFrame(someData)
   arComponents=["star","square"]
   nMaxComponents=3
   doPCA(df,arComponents,nMaxComponents)
```

Function Code:

```
# Function doPCA: performs PCA, displays scatter plot
# Inputs:  df (dataframe), arMarkers (array, plot marker settings),
#             nMaxComponents (integer, maximum # of PCA components)
#
function doPCA(df, arMarkers, nMaxComponents)
   # skipped PCA code
   nCount=1
   while nCount < nMaxComponents
      pltGet=scatter(...,marker=arMarkers[nCount],...)
      nCount=nCount+1
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia being a rather new language, the documentation is sparse and scattered, but this is essentially a PyPlot question.  The scatter plot marker is a symbol, and it should be passed as such.  So, the correct code to pass these data as parameters is:

Function Call (Works):

```
   using DataFrames
   pyplot()

   df=DataFrame(someData)
   arComponents=Symbol[:star, :square]
   doPCA(df,arComponents)
```

By the way, though Julia's error messages are a bit unwieldy, the hint is in the error output, wherever it reports that your bogus parameter isn't in proper Symbol[...,...] format.

Comment: It looks to me as if this is not a PyPlot question but rather a [Plots.jl](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#marker) question.

Also, `arComponents=[:star, :square]` is sufficient.

Comment: I clearly say that it is a PyPlot question in my answer - unfortunately, as I started my search for other sources of assistance, this was not obvious, since Julia is a new language.  Also, `arComponents=[:star,:square]` is NOT enough.  It's non-contextual answers like this that leave people like me searching StackOverflow.com for help like this.  Thank you!